# Sum of given telescopic series

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, telescopic-series

> A sequence is defined as follows: $a_1=\frac{1}{2}$ and $a_{n+1}=a_n^2+a_n$
>
> If $$S=\frac{1}{a_1+1}+\frac{1}{a_2+1}+\frac{1}{a_3+1}+.....+\frac{1}{a_{100}+1}$$
>
> Find $\lfloor S \rfloor$.

Now using $a_{n+1}=a_n^2+a_n$, I generated telescopic series to get
$S=2-\frac{1}{a_{101}}$ but I am not able to find $\frac{1}{a_{101}}$

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: This seems to be the same sum as here: [Sequence with promising sum.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3408310)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need actually ${1\over a_{101}}$. Since $a_{n+1}-a_n = a_n^2>0$ and $a_3>1$ we have $$0<{1\over a_{101}}<1$$ so

$$ 1 <2-{1\over a_{101}}<2 \Longrightarrow \lfloor S \rfloor = 1$$

Comment: Note that $a_n<1$, for $n<3$.  More verification is needed.

Comment: Why? How does this affect on $a_{101}$?

Comment: It depends on initial condition.  If $a_1$ belongs to the Mandelbrot Set, then $|a_{n}|<2 \:, \: \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: But $a_1 =1/2$. So $a_2 = 3/4$ and $a_3= 21/16>1$ so $a_n>1$ for all $n>2$.

Comment: So, you need to verify it by induction or else to make your answer complete.

Comment: What do I have to verify? I have already show that $a_{n+1}>a_n$ for all $n$.

Comment: @ChristianF So we cannot calculate $S$ in few steps ? I guess that is why question asked for integral part of $S$.