# Sequence with promising sum.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A sequence is defined as $a_{k+1}=a_k(a_k+1)$ and $a_1=\frac12$ for $k>0$. What is the smallest integer greater than
>   $$\frac{1}{a_1+1}+\frac{1}{a_2+1}+\frac{1}{a_3+1}\cdots+\frac{1}{a_{100}+1}?$$

Using the definition, $a_k+1=\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}$. So our sum is
$$\frac{a_1}{a_2}+\frac{a_2}{a_3}+\frac{a_3}{a_4}\cdots \frac{a_{100}}{a_{101}}$$
This looks promising, but I´m not sure how to proceed since I cannot find the explicit formula.

Comment: Source of this problem, please?

Comment: Another problem about the same sum: [Sum of given telescopic series](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2647653)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$A_{k+1}=A_k(A_k+1) \implies \frac{1}{A_{k}}- \frac{1}{A_{k+1}}=\frac{1}{A_k +1}~~~(11$$
By tescopic summing the required sum is $$S=\frac{1}{A_{1}}-\frac{1}{A_{101}}.~~~(2)$$
Starting with $A_1=1/2, A_2=3/4, A_3= 21/16, A_4 =777/256,...$ $A_k$ are increasing function of $k$ so $A_{101}$ will be very large. So from (2) it follows that $$2/3<S<2.$$

Comment: A little more explanation $$\dfrac1{A_{k+1}}=\dfrac{A_k+1-A_k}{(A_k+1)A_k}=?$$

Comment: Now, how would we find the explicit formula?

Comment: @lab Bhattacharjee In my first relation put $n=1, 2, 3, 4,...n.$ add these $n$ equations, cancellations will take place you will get my second equation which is the required sum.

Comment: @Baker013273213 Please see my eidt.