# Simplification of a telescopic series

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, telescopic-series

I've read this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2647653/sum-of-given-telescopic-series) on Math SE, but I cannot figure out the following:

> How to simplify $S$ to be $S=2-\frac{1}{a_{101}}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $a_{n+1}=a_n (a_n+1)$, it holds:
$\frac{1}{1+a_n}=\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{1}{a_n}-\frac{1}{a_{n+1}}$.
Therefore $S=\sum_{n=1}^{100} \frac{1}{1+a_n}=\sum_{n=1}^{100} \frac{1}{a_n}-\frac{1}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{1}{a_1}-\frac{1}{a_{101}}=2-\frac{1}{a_{101}}$.